# C# custom collection editor callback

Tags: c#, collections, callback, editor

I have created a custom collection editor which is started from the ... button in the property editor for a list of items. There is a wrapper class called CustomCollectionEditor which launches a form frmCustomCollectionEditor. To do this I've added the line

```
[Editor(typeof(CustomCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

on top of the collection (of strings) e.g.:

```
class Item
  {
    [Editor(typeof(CustomCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
      public string[] Items { get; set; }
  }
```

However, now I want to pass stuff back from CustomCollectionEditor to the item. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Hi, plenty of examples online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302334.aspx